# Moving Python AddIns to ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, python-addin, arcgis-pro-sdk

I have created a Python AddIn for ArcMap and it has been tested and functions very properly. However, I am looking online, and it seems like I have to go through a lot of processes just for it to function in ArcGIS Pro. I need to be able to do this quickly but I just haven't seen anywhere that would allow this to be a smooth transition.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no equivalent to the Python AddIns that you can write for ArcMap available for the ArcGIS Pro architecture.

The best attempt that I have made is at [Do ArcGIS Pro tasks support Python Toolbox tools which operate on Map Frames?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/173847/115)

Comment: That is so rough. I've never written in Visual Basic or C# before. All I need to do is be able to click on a point on the map and then use the coordinates from that point to be the input in a python geoprocessing tool. Does that sound like something that could be done quickly using SDK?

Comment: For that I think you could use a Feature Set in either a Python script tool or a Python Toolbox.

Comment: I will look into that. Thank you so much. I had done it previously by using an addin tool button but if there is a way for a tool to create the same results then that will save a lot of workarounds with visual studio

Comment: I can't understand the logic of that, all those hours (=money) put into python addins for them not to be supported in Pro. Even Desktop supports gp scripts back to 9.2 (as at 10.2.2). Daniel, if you need help getting started with C# or VB.net post a new question but before that you will need to obtain a compiler for Visual Studio, Express (free-ish) is not listed in the SDK requirements so you will probably need to purchase VS 2015 or 2017 to match your Visual Studio install to your ArcGIS pro https://github.com/esri/arcgis-pro-sdk/wiki#requirements so it's not to be undertaken lightly.